# Example of random variable not tight

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, weak-convergence

I'm studying Helly selection theorem and convergence of sequence of distribution function $F_n$ of r.v.

My professor highlighted that every sequence $F_n$ has a subsequence weakly convergent but the limit could be either a distribution or not. In order to be sure that the limit is actually a distribution I see we should ask the sequence to be relatively compact and I know Prohorov's theorem states that a family is relatively compact iff it is tight. Well, I was trying to convince myself of this fact. In other word, I'm asking, is there a random variable which is not tight and so its distribution does not have a subsequence converging weakly?

I see it must be a random variable escaping to infinity which is actually the contrary of tightness (I guess) but I can't think of any.

Comment: What about a sequence of uniform random variables concentrated at [n,n+1]

Comment: So we get $F_n(x)=1$ for x$\in [n,n+1]$ and 0 otherwise. In this way I see it isn't actually tight 'cause I can't take a compact such that $F_n(K^\complement ) < \varepsilon $. That's perfect! Now I'm wondering if $F_n$ converges weakly to the delta function? Am I wrong?

Comment: Actually  $F_n(x)=(x-n)^{+} \wedge 1$.   It converges pointwise to the null function. It does not converges weakly.

Comment: That's right thanks